# Import boolean values from excel file to database using laravel and mattwebsite excel

Tags: excel, laravel

this is the first time that I'm trying to import data from excel file to database using laravel.

In my database table I have a `int column` , it takes `0 or 1` , But in My `excel` I have data like `yes or no`.

How can I import this data as `0 or 1` value instead of `yes or no` value by using `mattwebsite excel package` ?

If you have any idea please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [eloquent-mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) in laravel

```
public function set{ColName}Attribute($value)
{
    if(!isset($value) || $value == 'no'){
        $value = 0;
     }else{
        $value = 1; 
    }
    $this->attributes['{ColName}'] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Fix condition, 1 presumably shouldn't be saved in case `!isset($value)`.

Comment: This is what I meant,i will edit it now . thanks .

Comment: Check logic of condition now. Better choice could be to use switch or match instead.